# Trying to define a function using indexed variables

Tags: function-construction

I have a list of indexed variables, for example `xx={x[2],x[4]}` and an expression which is a function of those indexed variables, say `hex=x[2]+x[4]`. I want to use `xx` and hex to define a function `h[]` such that `h[{a,b}]=a+b`. I tried `h[xx_]:=hex` and that doesn't work. What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

`xx = {x[2], x[4]};
hex = x[2] + x[4];`

`Module[{tmp1},
     tmp1 = Replace[xx, a1_ :> Module[{xx}, xx], {1}];
     SetDelayed @@ ({h[Pattern[#, _] & /@ xx], hex} /.MapThread[Rule, {xx, tmp1}])
 ];`

`h[{1, 2}]`